# Spring with elastic search

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am developing a spring application for basic CRUD operations along with flexible search functionalities. I am using elastic search as back end data store.

Following is the JSON document I am dealing with :-

```
{
    "event-id":"7700908",
    "date":"date:time",
    "expiry": "some date",
    "created-by":"",
    "type":"x1|business|x3",
    ...
    "dress-code": {
        "mime-type": "image|audio|video|text",
        "placeholder-type": "key|index",
        "en_us": "Dress code guidelines...",
        "en_in": "",
        "placeholders": [
            {
                "key": "foo-bar",
                "type": "snippet|image|quote",
                "content": {
                    "mime-type": "image|audio|video|text",
                    "en_us": "some instruction placeholder",
                    "en_in": "some instruction placeholder",
                    "fr_FR": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "events": {
        "event-id": "4534534",
        "event-instruction": {
            "mime-type": "audio|video|text",
            "placeholder-type": "key|index",
            "en_us": "The actual instruction, with/without placeholder (like put of 3d glasses etc...)",
            "en_in": "",
            "placeholders": [
                {
                    "key": "foobar",
                    "type": "snippet|image|quote",
                    "content": {
                        "mime-type": "image|audio|video|text",
                        "en_us": "some instruction placeholder",
                        "en_in": "some instruction placeholder",
                        "fr_FR": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "rules":""
        ...
    },
    "refs": [
        {
            "person-id":"445245524",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Then following data model would represent above json at server :-

```
public class Event {

    @JsonProperty("event-id")
    private String eventId;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;

    @JsonProperty("expiry")
    private String expiry;

    @JsonProperty("created-by")
    private String createdBy;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    ...

    @JsonProperty("dress-code")
    private DressCode dressCode;

    ...
}
```

As usual there are *Controller* and *Repository* classes. Controller class defines mapping from url to server method whereas Respository class implements all the necessary database operations.

Inserting and fetching records are quite basic. However, I am facing several issues writing functionality for search based on criteria provided by user. Below is my initial approach :-

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllEventsForCriteria(final Event event) 
{

        List<Map<String, Object>> resultAsList = new ArrayList<>();
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(buildQuery(event));
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        try {
            SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
            SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
                resultAsList.add(hit.getSourceAsMap());
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return resultAsList;
    }

    private QueryBuilder buildQuery(final Event event) {

        BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

        if (event.getEventId() != null) {
            QueryBuilder idTerm = QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", event.getQuizId());
            queryBuilder.must(idTerm);
        }
        if (event.getDate() != null) {
            QueryBuilder dateTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("date", event.getDate());
            queryBuilder.must(dateTerm);
        }
        if (event.getExpiry() != null) {
            QueryBuilder expiryTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("expiry", event.getExpiry());
            queryBuilder.must(expiryTerm);
        }
        if (event.getCreatedBy() != null) {
            QueryBuilder createdByTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("created-by", event.getCreatedBy());
            queryBuilder.must(createdByTerm);
        }
        if (event.getType() != null) {
            QueryBuilder typeTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", event.getType());
            queryBuilder.must(typeTerm);
        }
        if (event.getDressCode() != null) {
            if (event.getDressCode().getMimeType() != null) {
                QueryBuilder mimeTerm = QueryBuilders.termQuery("dressCode.mime-type", event.getDressCode().getMimeType());
                queryBuilder.must(mimeTerm);
            }
            if (event.getDressCode().getEnUs() != null) {
                QueryBuilder enUSTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("dressCode.en_us", event.getDressCode().getEnUs());
                queryBuilder.must(enUSTerm);
            }
            if (event.getInstructions().getEnIn() != null) {
                QueryBuilder enInTerm = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("dressCode.en_in", event.getDressCode().getEnIn());
                queryBuilder.must(enInTerm);
            }
        }

        return queryBuilder;
    }
```

There are two major issues I am facing with this approach :-

- User can search based on any combination of parameters. Is this approach more **general**?
- For some fields I need to make search return exact results. `matchQuery` would return all results whereas `termQuery` breaks the query into tokens. What is the way out here with/without making any changes to JSON.